# Importance of Following Procedure

Tags: design, technique, bench

I'm an amateur at woodworking/masonry/anything home-improvement related.

I'm building a bench, and the following (parts 7c and 7d) forms part of the bench's building procedure. I can't visualize nor understand those parts. Could someone exlplain why they're needed and maybe reference a visual?

http://www.amalgamatedstuff.com/bsatroop475/Docs/Troop475-bench-plans.pdf

1. Match each post with a specific seat 2 x 6 support brace
   a. Due to shrinkage, not all pieces will be the same size
   b. Use the specific seat brace to measure and cut the
   notch in the 6 x 6 so that it fits the seat brace
   *c. Use a circular saw set to the proper depth to create
   the cut for the shoulder that the brace will rest upon
   d. Use a plunge router to remove the remaining notch
   material. Make 2 passes.*

**IN any other context, steps c and d would make sense. I'm unsure why they're needed for building the particular bench (**

Comment: So long as you understand the basic way the lumber needs to be shaped and assembled, I imagine you could ignore the written procedure and set-to with a hand-saw, hand-drill, a few sheets of sandpaper and several cans of beer. It's a rustic seat, not a Louis XIV sofa. You could just make two perpendicular cuts with a hand saw. If its 1/4" out it will just add to the charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those instructions aren't very clear!  I read step #7 this way:

```
7: Cut notches in the seat posts. Here's hints on how to do it:
   a) Don't assume both braces are the same size.
   b) Use the seat brace itself to mark the area to be cut out.
   c) After you've marked it, start the notch by making a cut with a circular saw.
   d) Now that you have a nice cut, use a router to hog away the rest.
```

This is the notch they are talking about:

[image: Notch]

Does this help?

Comment: +1 The reason a router is used to remove the notched out material is the difficulty in cutting the end of a post with a circular saw - not enough balancing surface to be safe. Also the cut is about 5 1/2 inches deep. If the post were chocked upright in a brace, a hand saw might be an alternate approach